# Detox : IOS Simulator does not returns "onMessage: {"type":"ready","messageId":-1000,"params":{}}"

Tags: ios, react-native, automated-tests, detox

My App is Hybrid i.e IOS Native / React Native, at the time of "detox test --loglevel verbose", it gets stuck at "detox verb ws send: {"type":"isReady","params":{},"messageId":-1000}" but soon after I manually tap on a react native submodule (on ios simulator), it receives the "onMessage: {"type":"ready","messageId":-1000,"params":{}}" and fails the tests which i had initially written for IOS Native portion.

Here are the logs  [Detox_Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0S6t.png)

Points to Note

1. I have added this snippet also in xcode app launch "[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"RCTContentDidAppearNotification" object: nil];" but didn't solved the purpose.
2. I have installed detox in the folder where i have my react-native submodule, also  the xcode workspace is located in another folder.

Please guide through this, it will be really helpful.